# What is the point of beating Heroic mode for any adventure?

Tags: hearthstone

So I recently bought the League of Explorers as one of my first paid items in Hearthstone. I loved it, and how interesting all the cards were.

Now after I beat the default bosses, a new mode showed up named 'Heroic'. When reading the description the only thing different from normal mode is "Heroic mode is NOT for the faint of heart!", and within the section itself there was no treasure chest icons like in Normal.

What is the meaning of doing Heroic mode? It seems beating it should give you the golden version of the card normally unlocked but there is no text describing what you get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Adventures are usually very easy to not scare away casuals. To give experienced players a challenge as well they made the heroic mode. You fight the same bosses there as in the regular adventure, except they are **a lot** harder to beat.
While you can usually take your ladder decks to beat the normal adventure, you really need to fine-tune your decks for the heroic bosses.

To answer your question, the point of heroic is to offer experienced players a challenge. The only prize you get for beating all heroic bosses is a special card back.

> It seems beating it should give you the golden version of the card
>   normally unlocked [...]

Fun fact: Blizzard was actually thinking of doing that but they ended up not to, because they did not want to have too many things in the game, that casuals can not achieve.

Comment: Funfact is: I bet casuals have harder time by getting the golden variants for the cards by crafting via dust as it is now, as they had by getting them for beating heroic mode. You still can buy wings by gold imagine per 700 gold you would get in heroic the posibillity of 1 golden legendary 1~2 golden epics +  a handfull of golden commons/rares. Now for the same cards, try to get out the dust for crafting them out of 7 boosters... I just made the calculation for fun.... you had to get in 7 boosters on average 5,17 legendarys per booster to make enough dust to create the first wing fully golden.

Comment: @Zaibis the funny thing is that a booster only has 5 cards. So you can't even get 5.17 legendaries in a booster.

Comment: Yeah, they didn't deny the gold cards to avoid having something unachievable - they did it so that players who have earned or paid for the adventures still have to spend additional resources to get everything. Crafting is set up to encourage spending money to get more cards to dust.

Comment: @Samthere I agree that this might have been one of the reason for Blizzard to decide this way, but the official reason is the one I mentioned.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Yeah, fair! No issue with the answer, just couldn't not call out Blizzard on their BS :P